# Error while implementing prismatic joint

Tags: gazebo, ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,I tried to simulate prismatic joint in Gazebo and getting following error while implementing.

```
Could not find resource 'prismatic_joint' in 'hardware_interface::EffortJointInterface'
```

Here is the code

```
<joint name="prismatic_joint" type="prismatic">
  <parent link="linear_actuator_pole_link"/>
  <child link="sliding_mounting_plate_link"/>
  <origin xyz="0.035 0 -0.4795"/>
  <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
  <limit effort="0.1" lower="0" upper="1.02" velocity="0.15" />
</joint>
<transmission>
  <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
  <joint name="prismatic_joint">
    <hardwareInterface>EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
  </joint>
  <actuator name="prismatic_joint_motor">
    <hardwareInterface>EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
  </actuator>
</transmission>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277990/error-while-implementing-prismatic-joint/) by [ARB](https://answers.ros.org/users/32980/arb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2017-12-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

able to solve this...Transmission name was missing:)

---

Originally posted by [ARB](https://answers.ros.org/users/32980/arb/) with karma: 51 on 2017-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0